# Open Modal (bootstrap) from other html-file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website using `bootstrap`. But i'm come to somewhat of an dead-end. i've created a modal from an given example (see below). As you might see, this is a modal taken straight from their website.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nieuwe Taak toevoegen</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I open this dialog using a button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
```

But i want to keep my modals in seperate `aspx/html-files`. How can i open these modals when they are kept inside different `html/aspx - files` ?

**example:**
if the button is inside `index.Html` but the modal is inside `newTaskModal.html`, how would i open the modal? (If both are inside index.html, then there are no problems)

**Note:** I don't/can't use HTML5 (company-standards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using jquery, you could download the page using an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'newTaskModal.html',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    // todo:  add the html to the dom...
  }
});
```

If you're building a single page application you might want to check out a framework designed to solve this type of problem:
**[durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)**

Comment: Ideally! I just load the recieved html inside a div on my index.html and the problem is solved (can't believe i couldn't come up with that problem myself...). Thnx! That framework also looks quite usefull. I'll give it a try this weekend. Thanks for that aswell! :)

Answer (score 3):

Also you could if you are using JQuery to load your html page into into a matched element.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Go to http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use PHP? If so there is simple solution.

Your index will be index.php and where you want to have your modal just place this code

```
<?php include "newTaskModal.html"; ?>
```

Comment: I know of the possiblity to use ´php-include´but i'm searching more in the direction of a pure HTML/javascript-Solution

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1 **Use below  code for link:**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="MyModal.html" data-target="#MyModal" data-backdrop="static">OPEN MODAL</a>
```

STEP 2 **Use below code for modal window**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog model-sm">`enter code here
        <div class="modal-content"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

STEP 3 Create MyModal.html and place some text.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
Modal Contents
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">OK</button>
    </div>
```

Note: This may not work local html. works only on server!