# get a button name using document.getElementById on a different html folder and file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal popup where i am trying to trigger it when i click on a button. the button however is in a different folder and file. will i be able to link it?

MODAL: (main.html)

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Welcome, New White Card Holder!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body spacer-left spacer-right">
        <br>
        <h3>Congratulations, you are entitled for a 30-day free trial of our Elite Membership.</h3>
        <h3>If you wish to avail of our other membership options, click here.</h3>
        <h3>Enjoy a wealth of deals for wellness!</h3>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

REGISTER BUTTON:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
```

[image: folders]

Once again I'm trying to get my register button to my `var btn = document.getElementById("");` in the **modal_popup.js** file, but both are separated by folders as seen in the above image. I'm wondering if it is possible to do and if so, what should I add to `document.getElementById("")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427371/open-modal-bootstrap-from-other-html-file

Answer (score 0):

1. A button with the type "submit" will reload the page since submit is used for forms to post form data to the server. Try changing the type to button. Different browsers default buttons to different behavior if the type is not specified.
2. I'm guessing your input element is mean't to be a button so I would change that to a button tag instead.
3. Your `btn` variable should be `var btn = document.getElementById("register");`
4. If the modal is not a part of the DOM, it will not work. Make sure the HTML is on the same page as your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below in register.html :

```
<jsp:element name="script">
    <jsp:attribute name="type">text/javascript</jsp:attribute>  
        <jsp:attribute name="src">
           <c:url value="/pages/js/modal_popup.js"/>
        </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body></jsp:body>
</jsp:element>
```