# Render output to Modal using Slim framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slim

I am creating a web page which will list all the hosts names when the
website is accessed, each of the server is of type button, so when a
user clicks the button, it has to call the function(getHostDetails)
and display the output in a modal div tag as below

When the button({i.sname}} - Server Name) is clicked it has to call the
function "getHostDetails" by passing the the parameter({{i.sID}} -
Server ID) and the output of this function should be displayed in the
below modal div.

I am using Slim framework 3.x

Below section contains the html code:

```html
<tr>
    {% for i in srvcontainer  %}
    <td class="text-center h9 th-sm">
        <a href="/showinfo/{{i.sID}}">
        <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-info btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#info">{{i.sname}}</button>
        </a>
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

<div id='info' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                <h4 class='modal-title'>Test</h4>
            </div>
             <div class='modal-body'>
             {% for h in srvinfo  %}
                 <tr><td>{{h.CPU}}</td><td>{{h.Memory}}</td></tr>
             {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contain the below codes index.php

```php
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) use ($app) {
    $wp = new reports();
    $wps = $wp->getHosts();
    return $this->view->render($response, 'wps.html', array(
        "wps" => $wps));
});

$app->get('/showinfo/{sID}', function ($request, $response, $args) use ($app) {
    $wp = new reports();
    $wsid = $args['sID'];
    $srvinfo = $wp->getHostDetails($wsid);
    return $this->view->render($response, 'wps.html', array(
        "srvinfo" => $srvinfo));
});
```

Request your help on this.

Comment: Nope it is not a duplicate, if you check my requirement it is slightly different than what is answered in the link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427371/open-modal-bootstrap-from-other-html-file).